# How to create an app to read ntfs usb without rooting android

Tags: android, filesystems, android-sdcard, ntfs

I want develop an app which can read NTFS formatted SDCARD. How should I proceed? Which permissions and intents should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access block devices if your Android device is not rooted.

Comment: but their are some apps like es explorer which shows data of ntfs formatted pen drive . can you tell how they are working?

Comment: You asked about the internal sdcard, not about external OTG devices.